# How to disable JSLint ES6 errors with const and let in Adobe Brackets?

Tags: javascript, configuration, syntax-error, jslint, adobe-brackets

I have Googled and looked through this site everywhere, but I can only find answers for JSHint instead of JSLint. 
To get rid of the "use function form of use strict" error I add in `/*jslint node: true */`.
But to disable errors for using `const` and `let` I can't seem to find anything. JSHint has esversion: 6 but this doesn't work on JSLint.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I've got a theory, but it is too much work to test it. Put code in your question, not pictures of code.

Comment: The error is saying that you shouldn't `'use strict';` within the global scope. This is a common recommendation as it can enable strict mode for the entire application, possibly breaking other scripts being used. Also: ["*JSLint will recognize the good parts of ES6 with the `es6` option.*"](http://www.jslint.com/help.html#es6)

Comment: @Quentin the entire code is: http://pastebin.com/GcU3vKsE

Comment: @JonathanLonowski so I should wrap my entire code into a function? Even when using it in NodeJS?

Comment: @bdbdbd If you're using Node.js, then no. Node will already wrap your files in a function to create its "[*module scope*](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects)."

Comment: So apparently JSLint does not support ES6?

Comment: It does. Maybe it's an outdated version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Preferences API:

```
var PreferencesManager = brackets.getModule("preferences/PreferencesManager");

prefs = PreferencesManager.getExtensionPrefs("jslint");

prefs.set("options.es6", true);
```

Or set it one of the config files:

- the `brackets.json` file of the user directory

or:

- the `.brackets.json` file of the project directory:

As such:

```
{
    "jslint.options": {
        "es6": true
     }
}
```

**References**

- [brackets: .brackets.json](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/.brackets.json)
- [brackets: jslint extension - main.js](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/extensions/default/JSLint/main.js)
- [brackets wiki: Preferences Overview](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Preferences-Overview)
- [PreferencesManager - Brackets API](http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/preferences/PreferencesManager.html)

Comment: This is a useful resource to find the related files https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets