# Brackets ESLint errors. JS

Tags: javascript, eslint

When I write code in Brackets I see red errors. They are not affect for result, but how can I avoid them?
[image]

Comment: Please remove 'brackets' tag. Based on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets, DO NOT USE THIS for the IDE, use [adobe-brackets] instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable JSLint ES6 errors with const and let in Adobe Brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378977/how-to-disable-jslint-es6-errors-with-const-and-let-in-adobe-brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either set the es6 environment to true or set ecmaVersion to 6 in you ES Lint configuration file.

See http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 6
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem i researched about it, but creating a json file in the projects root folder cleared my issue. please follow the link 
[solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067263/eslint-showing-errors-in-brackets)

I also found other possible ways to solve this, read these links you will know and understand
[experience of other person with solution](https://the-sourceterous.ghost.io/brackets-editor-disable-jslint-and-use-jshint-instead-2/)

also visit the link provided in brackets.json file.
they mention clearly how to use brackets preferences.[brackets preferences](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences)